# When and why to check if an element exists with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom

I recently wrote a small script that made a simple show/hide manipulation to an unordered list.

From my understanding, jQuery will only execute a function if the element in question exists (therefore if it's 'true'). So there is no practical reason in doing a check to see if the length of the element is bigger than 0, if it has a parent node which is body and so on. Correct?

If the above is accurate, when would actually such a check be helpful?

http://jsbin.com/ehicik/1/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the action you want to perform could cascade into errors if an element doesn't exist, it would be helpful to do a check first. Something fairly trivial (like show/hide) probably wouldn't warrant a check.

(Although it's good programming practice to make sure everything works as intended, and fails gracefully. A check would help with that, or at least a try... catch statement.)

Comment: Thanks, do you have any quick example of such an action that could cascade into errors?

Comment: Fading in another element on fadeout of a non-existent one... the second element would never appear ;) for smaller applications it's trivial, but when you start chaining events and getting ever-more complicated, it's best to be thorough.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct, jQuery will only attempt the method called if it exists.

However using:

```
if($("#someElement").length) { ... Do Stuff };
```

can be very useful if you are doing a blend of jQuery and JavaScript - I find you often can't achieve everything with jQuery and you'll get script errors if you try JavaScript operations on non-existing objects.

For example, I wish to copy "Shipping Address" from "Billing Address" - but my page will only render "Shipping Address" if the products are shippable (downloaded products do not need shipping) - So I check if "shipping address" exists before I do any further work in jQuery.

This is just a rough example, and I appreciate you could just not render the jQuery button as well - That said, if you have a central `.js` file, it's more relevant as you may have some more generic JS that will try and run on each page.

So that's when I'd check for an object existing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how important it is to you/your script that the element actually exists. Let's say the rest of your script depends on some data you need to retrieve from an element, and that element doesn't exist, you'll want to know about it an act upon it. In that case a check is obviously very useful.

In the case of a simple show/hide, the need for this is probably minimal.

Answer (score 0):

Here length property will return number of elements which have been selected by `$('#id')`.
if it return zero then it means no item matched or selected.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert($('#id').length);
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: He knows that, just isn't sure of how useful such a check is.